# How to list each distinct element and count all occurances of each element in XSLT/XPATH?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, count

I would like to reduce a list to distinct elements but count the number of each occurence of that element:

```
<list>
  <entry>A</entry>
  <entry>B</entry>
  <entry>A</entry>
  <entry>A</entry>
  <entry>B</entry>
</list>
```

aimed result:

A - 3 [occurences]

B - 2 [occurences]

I have tried to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="count()" />
```

but it either counts all occurences of the "entry" element (5) or the number different "entry" elements (2, being A and B).

My latest try was to combine two for-each loops (never done before), but that doesn't work either:

```
<xsl:variable name="occurences">
<xsl:for-each select="//entry[not(.=preceding::entry)]">
<xsl:value-of select="count()" />
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//entry">
<p>
     <xsl:value-of select="." /> - <xsl:value-of select="$occurences" />
</p>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

[An XPath function was called with the wrong number of arguments.]

I'd be grateful for any hint...

Thank you!
John

Comment: Can you say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? Thank you!

Comment: Hello Tim! I am used to XSLT 1.0 but ready to learn XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @JohnX It's not a question of what you are willing to learn, but rather what your XSLT processor will support. If you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor, you should use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) (or, if your processor supports it, the EXSLT [set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) extension function. If you have an XSLT 2.0 processor at your disposal, you can use the [distinct-values()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-distinct-values) function.

Comment: Thank you! But I am not just lookin for getting out distinct elements, but a combination of distinct elements and all occurances of each element.
I guess in XSLT 2.0 it should be something like:
`<table>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="list" group-by="entry">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>`
Unfortunately this does not work out. Any idea? Would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can indeed use XSLT 2.0, you can use the `xsl:for-each-group` here, but you need to select `entry` elements, not the single `list` element, as it is entry elements you wish to group.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <table> 
      <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="."> 
         <tr> 
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td> 
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></td> 
         </tr> 
       </xsl:for-each-group> 
     </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, here is how you would do it with `distinct-values`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="entry" match="entry" use="." />
  <xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

  <xsl:template match="list">

    <table> 
      <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(entry)"> 
         <tr> 
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td> 
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('entry', ., $root))"/></td> 
         </tr> 
       </xsl:for-each> 
     </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the third parameter in the `key` function, as within the loop you are no longer in the context of the main document.

Comment: Wow, just checked out both solutions and both work. Thank you so much! I have saved the stylesheets as tim01.xsl and tim02.xsl. (And just to finally make it explicit: I have an XSLT 2.0 processor at my disposal.) Best wishes,